# Search for folders that contain filetypes

Tags: macos, search, smart-folders

For example, how do you search for all folders that contain ".mp3" files (on OS X)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using Finder, but you can easily find these folders via Terminal

```
find . -name '*.mp3' | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort -u
```

Some explanations:

- `find` lists all files (and their paths) ending in `mp3` in the current folder and everything "beneath" it
- `sed` strips away the last part of each line produced by `find` which does not contain a `/` (which practically results in the file name getting removed)
- The result so far is a list of folders containing `mp3` files. If a folder contains more than one such file, it will be listed several times so we use `sort -u` (*u*nique) to remove duplicates while sorting.